# Easy way to implement simple UI with .net

Tags: c#, .net, webui

I'm mostly working with backend development in .net, but I need implementing web UI (+ possibly mobile app) for my pet project. Can someone "list" possible ways to do it? Maybe something about no code framework? I didn't find such stuff for .net eco system.
NOTE: I can work with asp.net in general, but it looks overkill for me given it's only for pet project.

Comment: what means zerocode?

Comment: I meant `no code`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-code_development_platform

Answer (score -2, accepted):

These are all the different UI frameworks available in .net ecosystem:

- Asp.Net Core MVC
- Asp.Net Core Razor Pages
- Blazor web assembly (SPA)
- Blazor server side (SPA)

I recommend you to use razor pages,
It's great for small projects, easy to learn, and super clean syntax.

If you prefer to have a SPA application,
try out Blazor server side.

Links :

[Introduction to Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor)

[Introduction to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

---

If you're not familiar with html/css, use a css framework, like bootstrap

Comment: yeah. I know, but as I wrote, I'm not really familiar with HTML/Razor controls, markup and etc. I would prefer to use some kind of designer (like in WPF or WinForms) where I can just simply drag and drop controls and assign event handlers (preferably without web specific). Unless something like this is possible

Comment: In modern .net, there isn't a drag and drop design system, there is web forms but it's for .net framework and it's obselete

Comment: maybe it's possible to combine some approaches not initially for .net? Like creating html markup in designer somewhere and then just import it to let's say asp.net mvc? And then I will just need to assign handlers in controller?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, create html/css design where ever you want, then use it in .net, use razor pages

Comment: If you're going to create web pages then you're going to have to deal with HTML, CSS and JavaScript at some point. Just because it's a pet project doesn't really mean you should treat it like a second-class project. Take this as an opportunity to at least learn the basics of these technologies.

Comment: `to have to deal with HTML, CSS and JavaScript at some point` => yeah, but given that I need super simple UI (like few buttons + list), I hoped I can avoid diving into web specific details

Comment: `create html/css design where ever you want,` - can you recommend something? Better if it's free

Comment: Adobe XD (paid), Figma (free) then convert to html

Comment: FYI comments are not for extended discussion - they're just for clarification. Also, the question is off-topic (asking for recommendations). Continuing to add recommendations (both as an answer and in follow-on comments) doesn't fit here on Stack Overflow.